# Setter property vs data property in prototype

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain the following behavior?

```
var p = {
  name: "John",
  set age(value) {
    console.log("Age set to", value);
  }
}

var obj = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, p);

obj.name = "Jill"; // Doesn't alter the name on prototype, creates a new property on obj
obj.age = 22; // Calls the setter on prototype
```

Why is the assigning to `age` invoking the setter on the prototype, while assigning to `name` creates a new property on `obj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how JavaScript works. When `=` is used to assign to a property, the engine will look up in the object's prototype chain to find the first property descriptor matching the property name. If such a descriptor is found, if the descriptor is an accessor (that is, with a setter and/or getter), the setter will be invoked. Otherwise, if the descriptor is a data descriptor, there's no setter, and the new value will be assigned to the *own property* of the instance.

This process of looking up the prototypes to find a descriptor is described in the specification here: [OrdinarySetWithOwnDescriptor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarysetwithowndescriptor). The bold below is my commentary.

1. Assert: IsPropertyKey(P) is true.
2. If ownDesc is undefined, then

   1. Let parent be ? O.[[GetPrototypeOf]]().
   2. If parent is not null, then

      1. Return ? parent.[[Set]](P, V, Receiver). **This is the recursive call. `ownDesc` is set to the first ancestor which contains a descriptor for this property name.**
   3. Else,

      1. Set ownDesc to the PropertyDescriptor { [[Value]]: undefined, [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true }.
3. If IsDataDescriptor(ownDesc) is true, then

   1. If ownDesc.[[Writable]] is false, return false.
   2. If Type(Receiver) is not Object, return false.
   3. Let existingDescriptor be ? Receiver.[[GetOwnProperty]](P).
   4. If existingDescriptor is not undefined, then

      1. If IsAccessorDescriptor(existingDescriptor) is true, return false.
      2. If existingDescriptor.[[Writable]] is false, return false.
      3. Let valueDesc be the PropertyDescriptor { [[Value]]: V }.
      4. Return ? Receiver.[[DefineOwnProperty]](P, valueDesc). **With a data descriptor, the instance - that is, the `Receiver` - gets the new value assigned to it, regardless of where in the prototype chain the descriptor was found.**
   5. Else,

      1. Assert: Receiver does not currently have a property P.
      2. Return ? CreateDataProperty(Receiver, P, V).
4. Assert: IsAccessorDescriptor(ownDesc) is true.
5. Let setter be ownDesc.[[Set]].
6. If setter is undefined, return false.
7. Perform ? Call(setter, Receiver, « V »). **Otherwise, the setter is called.**
8. Return true.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to a property, it first searches the prototype chain for a setter. If a setter is found, it is simply executed.

If no setter is found, an ordinary property is either created or updated in the object itself. Assigning a property never assigns to an inherited property by itself (a setter could do so).